# Como pasar a funcion

Tags: c++

Esto es lo que tengo pero no funciona, como pueden darse cuenta uso listas con estructuras. Quisiera pasar la funcion altas() como valor, que parametros van dentro de la funcion. He probado de todo y no me sale. He leido acerca de STL (Standard Template Library) en C++ pero no encuentro como pasar una lista a funcion.
Saludos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Trabajador {
    string nombre;
    int numero;
    double sueldo;
    int horas;
};

//Definicion de funciones
void altas();

int main()
{
    list <Trabajador> tr;
    Trabajador t;
    char opcion;

    do {
        cout << "\n----------------------------\nBienvenido                     usuario\n\n";
        cout << "A - Altas: Agregar a trabajadores\n";
        cout << "B - Consultas generales\n";
        cout << "C - Consultas por claves\n";
        cout << "D - Consultas por nombres\n";
        cout << "E - Salir\n\n";
        cout << "Selecciona una opcion: ";
        cin >> opcion; cin.ignore();

        switch(opcion) {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                altas();
            break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                //ord_nombre();
            break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                //clave();
            break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                //bus_nombre();
            break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                cout << "Saliendo del programa \n";
            break;
            default:
                cout << "Opcion no valida";
            break;
        }
    } while ((opcion != 'e') && (opcion!='E'));

    return 0;
}

void altas() {
    int x;

    for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ";
        getline(cin,a.nombre);
        cout << "Ingrese el numero del trabajador: ";
        cin >> a.numero;
        cout << "Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: ";
        cin >> a.sueldo;
        cout << "Ingrese las horas trabajadas: ";
        cin >> a.horas;
        tr.push_back(a);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

De la manera tradicional (sin listas) es más facil de hacer.
Inclusive tuve una respuesta, pero adaptandolo a mi codigo no funciono. Que mas puedo intentar.

Comment: Prueba con `void altas(Trabajador &a);`

Comment: Por favor pon en el código lo que intentaste. El lugar importa en C++.

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas cambiar valores de variables o estructuras dentro de una función y que este cambio sea "permanente" para todo el código y no únicamente la función en local debes pasar los parámetros por referencia, es decir, pasarle a la función la dirección de memoria donde tienes alojada tu variable o en este caso tu estructura.

El código que buscas, junto con la llamada a la función sería el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_TRABAJADORES    1

struct Trabajador {
    string nombre;
    int numero;
    float sueldo;
    int horas;
};

void altas(Trabajador &trabajador) {

    for (int index=0; index<NUM_TRABAJADORES; index++) {
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ";
        getline(cin,trabajador.nombre);
        cout << "Ingrese el numero del trabajador: ";
        cin >> trabajador.numero;
        cout << "Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: ";
        cin >> trabajador.sueldo;
        cout << "Ingrese las horas trabajadas: ";
        cin >> trabajador.horas;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    
    Trabajador trabajador;  // Declaramos la estructura trabajador de tipo "Trabajador"
    
    altas(trabajador);  // Pasamos la estructura como argumento
    
    cout << "Mostrando datos fuera de la función para ver que se han guardado bien desde la función: " << endl;
    cout << "Nombre: " << trabajador.nombre << endl;
    cout << "Número: " << trabajador.numero << endl;
    cout << "Sueldo: " << trabajador.sueldo << endl;
    cout << "Horas: " << trabajador.horas << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Fíjate cómo manejamos la estructura dentro de la función mediante las direcciones de memoria pasadas por `&a`, y luego una vez fuera de la función mostramos los datos de la estructura que tenemos en el `main`, siendo ésta la misma que hemos pasado a la función. Los datos se han quedado guardados perfectamente.

Por otro lado, intentas meter un `for` para intuyo que incluir más datos de trabajadores, pues bien, para que eso lo puedas hacer debes crearte un array de estructuras, porque sino estarás machacando las regiones de memoria continuamente con datos nuevos y sólo guardarás el último dato introducido. Por lo tanto, cuando declares tu estructura hazlo de la forma `Trabajador trabajadores[NUM_TRABAJADORES];`, y ahora ya sí podrías usar un bucle `for` para ir metiendo datos en cada elemento del array (que ahora cada elemento es una nueva estructura) y además también deberás usar otro bucle `for` en caso de que quieras imprimir los datos de todo el array de estructuras que tienes

Por último, te aconsejo que cuando declares variables le pongas un nombre con un mínimo de criterio, y no llamarle `a`.

Comment: Podrias pasarme tu mail para mandarte el codigo completo, espero que me ayudes.
Salu2.

Comment: Obviamente no. Cualquier duda que tengas referente a tú código, lo que has intentado, qué errores te dan, etc. Postéalos aquí y entre todos trataremos de ayudarte.